# Please explain char* return type in C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, operator-overloading, c-strings

I have written a simple C++ code, and its working fine. But I don't know how it is working. I am just replacing `"l"` with `"r"` using `myfun()`.
The return type of `myfun()` is `char*`. If I am returning `&(str[0])`, that is, only the address of the first element of the array, then why is it printing the complete string `"herloworld"`? Please explain what `return &(str[0]);` is doing.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char* myfun(char str[])
{
    str[2] = 'r';
    return &(str[0]);
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "helloworld";
    char* word;
    word = myfun(str);
    cout << word;
}
```

Comment: Note that `return &(str[0]);` is exactly equal to `return &(*str);` which is the same as just `return str;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator << is overloaded for the type char * such a way that it expects that the used pointer of the type char * points to the first character of a string.

So the operator outputs all characters of the passed string until the zero character `'\0'` is encountered.

Also pay attention to that arrays used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

So this call

```
word = myfun(str);
```

is equivalent to

```
word = myfun( &str[0]);
```

On the other hand, a function parameter having an array type is implicitly adjusted to pointer to the element type.

So this function declaration

```
char* myfun(char str[]);
```

is equivalent to the following declaration

```
char* myfun(char *str);
```

The both declarations declare the same one function.

And within the function instead of this return statement

```
return &(str[0]);
```

you could write

```
return str;
```

Correspondingly in main you could write

```
cout << myfun(str);
```

without declaring and using the intermediate pointer `word`.